# How to install GCC 4.9 or GCC 5 on Debian Stretch?

Tags: debian, package-management, gcc

To build an old program for use in my Debian GNU/Linux box I need either GCC 4.9 or GCC 5. GCC 6+ will not work without changing the sources (that, for several reasons, I cannot change).

So I want to install GCC 4.9 or GCC 5, but I can't find a package.

Is there a faster way than building them from sources? (possibly scriptable)

Comment: GCC 5 is still available in [unstable](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/gcc-5); depending on your exact requirements that might be sufficient...

Comment: @StephenKitt I need to build a rump kernel (see https://github.com/rumpkernel/buildrump.sh ) and while it used to build fine on Jessie, I have several spurious errors in Stretch. I'd prefer to avoid apt pinning, since the process should be reproducible.

Comment: Hmmm I googled it, and it says kernel for the Cloud...mind you my asking what is a rump kernel and the usefulness of one for Linux?

Comment: A rump kernel is a NetBSD kernel running in user space on a target host (Linux in this case). It's uses depends on your needs, obviously. For example, it's pretty useful in OS development, to leverage NetBSD drivers and application.